# How do I read arbitrary big number at the end of textView?

Tags: java, android, string, textview

I display score of a player in my activity in my textView.

[image: ddd]

I was doing this:

```
int first_player_score  = Character.getNumericValue(points1_as_string.charAt(points1_as_string.length() - 1));
```

I found very stupid bug - the line above only reads **LAST** integer, so if the score is 6, it will read 6 and store it properly.

If the score grows to 2digit number, like 25, it will read 5!

As the last character.

Now I wonder how can I read score out of a string if it is more than 9?

It can be 3 digit, or 4 digit number, so charAt will not work.

Comment: I don't see why the question has been downvoted ... It is perfectly legitimate (upvoting it)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can `split` the string into two parts and take 2nd.

```
 int first_player_score= Integer.parseInt(points1_as_string.split(":")[1]);
```

Comment: you win I was about to post this answer

Comment: looks good, but when i tried it, it fails if there is a whitespace after "points: 14", it reads " 14" and throws an exception, but still i accept it.

Comment: use `trim()` to trim the space. `points1_as_string.split(":")[1].trim()`